# Wordpress Database Connection Error - PHP7 using MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

I have a localhost development environment using MAMP Pro, with a Wordpress website working successfully using PHP 5.6.8. Changing the host to PHP 7.0.13 (and changing nothing else) results in the error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or
>   directory in [edited path]/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
>
> **Error establishing a database connection**
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database
>   server at localhost:3306. This could mean your host’s database server
>   is down.

[Screenshot of Complete Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7j0I.jpg)

wp-config.php definitely has correct username, password, hostname and the database is running. Solutions to similar issues/warnings suggest the MySQL socket path in php.ini file could be wrong, but I have compared that file across the two php versions and they are the same.

I am using the latest versions of MAMP Pro (4.1) and Wordpress (4.7.4), as well as OS X (10.12.4). Also, the website works fine again when changing the host back to PHP 5.6.8.

No idea what else to do/check. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress 4.6 later version is not supported in Php 7.0 So please Reinstall Php 5.6 and check .so working

Comment: Do you mean there is an issue with a specific version of Wordpress? as Wordpress has supported PHP7 for a few years/releases, here at the current requirements https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

After updating to PHP7 you need to check the path to the mysql.sock.

Open the php.ini file and correct the path

```
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/bin/IDONTKNOW...../mysql.sock
```

Comment: The mysql.sock path is the same in the 5.6.8 php.ini file and 7.0.13 php.ini file which is: `mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: hmm,,, have you tried 172.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your Wordpress config?

Comment: Just tried 172.0.0.1 and 172.0.0.1:3306 ... on both php versions ... I get a 500 Internal Server error

Comment: So you're getting a 500 server error after you've changed the connection address from localhost:3306 to 127.0.0.1:3306 while still using PHP5.6.8? This should not happen. Check your /etc/hosts file if there is a record for 127.0.0.1 localhost.